# i want to expand div to left with its hidden child divs?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to make sidebar div which have child divs hidden in it.when rollover the parent div it will expand and child divs exposed and on rollout div back to its original size collapse.
I want my sidebar similar to this one. http://www.hosting.com/ its contact sidebar and i really want like this.

**CSS**

```
#Sidebar {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    top: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    background-image: url(chat.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    background-color: #F90;
    }
#Sidebar:hover {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}
.divchild {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #0F3;
    top: 5px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

**Html**

```
<a href="#">
<div class="Sidbaredges" id="Sidebar">
 <div class="divchild"></div>
 </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/mqzMx/

CSS

```
#Sidebar {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    top: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    background-image: url(chat.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    background-color: #F90;


}
#Sidebar:hover {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
}
.divchild {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #0F3;
    top: 7px;
    left: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function mouse_over()
{
    document.getElementById('divchild').style.display = 'block';
}
function mouse_out()
{
    document.getElementById('divchild').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#Sidebar {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    top: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    background-image: url(chat.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    background-color: #F90;
}
#Sidebar:hover {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}
.divchild {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #0F3;
    top: 5px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

</style>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>css test</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#">
<div class="Sidbaredges" id="Sidebar" onMouseOver="mouse_over();" onMouseOut="mouse_out();">
  <div class="divchild" id="divchild" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I also use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle is right used `css` and `jquery`

http://jsfiddle.net/UcQf4/3/

Answer (score 0):

Check this DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/hGKLj/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Sidebar, #Sidebar .divchild").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({ right: '0px'}, 600);
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({ right: '-170px'}, 600);
    });
});
```

Comment: this is great work but why this is not working on my browser and on Dreamweaver? :(

Comment: TypeError: $(...) is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

$(document).ready(function () {


on this line my firebub is showing error which i mentioned above.
and its not working in my Dreaweaver and in any browser.

Comment: have you include jquery library? like this...<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });